# Calling Generic Java function at the Abstract level

Tags: java, generics

Say I have an Abstract generic class:

```
public abstract class QuestionObject<T extends Answerable<?>> {   
    public abstract T returnAnswerable();
    public abstract void renderQuestionLayout(T answer);
}
```

and a companion generic class to go with it:

```
public interface Answerable<T> {
...
}
```

I have a bunch of subclasses that extend QuestionObject and have their own particular Answerable. So for example, a TrueFalseQuestion would be declared with a TrueFalseAnswer:

```
public class TrueFalseQuestion extends QuestionObject<TrueFalseAnswer> {
...
}
```

Let's saw I want to call the method renderQuestionLayout at the QuestionObject level. Is that possible? Something like:

```
QuestionObject<?> q = getCurrentQuestion();
Answerable<?>a = getAnswer();
q.renderQuestionLayout(a);
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your last code snippet:

```
QuestionObject<?> q = getCurrentQuestion();
Answerable<?>a = getAnswer();
q.renderQuestionLayout(a);
```

The `?` wildcard does not help the compiler determine which version of `renderQuestionLayout` to call. Right now, `q` is an instance your abstract parent class where the method has an abstract declaration.

You'll need to explicitly cast to the appropriate subclass type, or rethink your design a little bit so you don't have casts everywhere :p

Comment: I figured this might be the answer (explicitly casting). Do you think this is an example of bad design? What would a redesign look like? Thx.

Comment: Well, if you have too many subclasses, doing the casts everywhere can get pretty nasty. My suggestion would be to use a factory of some kind to get instances of the particular subclass that you need.